# GoogleTest Mocking object method call fail

Tags: c++, mocking, googletest

Hi so this is my first time utilizing googleTest Mocking. The general setup of the project is that coffeeMachine has an object coffeeStorage and coffeeStockService that it calls methods from coffeeMachine methods. I'm trying to create a mock test for the objects coffeeStorage and coffeeStockService but it's not recognizing the Expected Calls when I assign the mock objects to the coffeeMachine instance.

Trying to implement GoogleTest's mocking test framework but it's not recognizing the EXPECTED_CALL and also not letting me use mockedCoffeeStorage as a parameter to the method calls for mockedCoffeeStockService.. StockService Expected Call is because CoffeeMachine is also calling that but I passed in the coffeeStorage as a parameter. Is that possible for a mock object to cause a method that is using another mock object as the parameter and still expect the method to be called? Should I refactor and not include all the object references to the methods for CoffeeMachine since I already declare a CofeeStorage and CoffeeStockService object? Thank you so much

```
class coffeeMachine {
    public:
        coffeeStorage* CoffeeStorage;
        coffeeStockService* CoffeeStockService;
        bool coffeeServed = false;
        coffeeMachine(coffeeStorage* CoffeeStorage, coffeeStockService* CoffeeStockService);
        void start(string langIn);
        void stop();
        void descale();
        void showSettings();
        void hideSettings();
        map<string, string> getSetting();
        string message(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage);
        void takeCoffee(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage);
        void fillTank(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage, coffeeStockService& CoffeeStockService);
        void fillBeans(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage, coffeeStockService& CoffeeStockService);
        void emptyGrounds(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage, coffeeStockService& CoffeeStockService);
        bool isDescalingNeeded();

class coffeeStorage {
    private:
        int waterStorage;
        int beanStorage;
        int trashStorage;

    public:
        //virtual ~coffeeStorage(){}
        coffeeStorage();
        virtual void takeCoffeeStorage();
        virtual void setWaterStorage(int amount);
        virtual void setBeansStorage(int amount);
        virtual void emptyTrashStorage();
        virtual int checkWater();
        virtual int checkBeans();
        virtual int checkTrashStorage();
};

class mockCoffeeStorage : public coffeeStorage {
    private:
        int waterStorage;
        int beanStorage;
        int trashStorage;

    public:

    MOCK_METHOD(void, takeCoffeeStorage, (), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, setWaterStorage, (int amount), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, setBeansStorage, (int amount), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, emptyTrashStorage, (), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(int, checkWater, (), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(int, checkBeans, (), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(int, checkTrashStorage, (), (override));
};

coffeeMachine::coffeeMachine(coffeeStorage* CoffeeStorage_, coffeeStockService* CoffeeStockService_){

    waterHardness = "2";
    grinder = "medium";
    started = false;
    coffeeServed = false;
    settingsDisplayed = false;

    CoffeeStorage = CoffeeStorage_;
    CoffeeStockService = CoffeeStockService_;

    message(*CoffeeStorage_);
    descale();
    fillTank(*CoffeeStorage_, *CoffeeStockService_);
    fillBeans(*CoffeeStorage_, *CoffeeStockService_);
    emptyGrounds(*CoffeeStorage_, *CoffeeStockService_);
}

string coffeeMachine::message(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage){
        if(!started) return "";

        if (settingsDisplayed) return i18n("settings");
        if (CoffeeStorage.checkWater() <= 10) return i18n("tank");
        if (CoffeeStorage.checkBeans() < 3) return i18n("beans");
        if (CoffeeStorage.checkTrashStorage() >= 30) return i18n("grounds");
        if (isDescalingNeeded()) return i18n("descale");
        return i18n("ready");
}

void coffeeMachine::takeCoffee(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage){
       if (CoffeeStorage.checkWater() == 0 || CoffeeStorage.checkBeans() == 0) {
            coffeeServed = false;
        } else {
            coffeeServed = true;
            CoffeeStorage.takeCoffeeStorage();
            countdownToDescale -= 1;
        }
}

void coffeeMachine::fillTank(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage, coffeeStockService& CoffeeStockService){
    CoffeeStockService.restockWater(CoffeeStorage);
}

void coffeeMachine::fillBeans(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage, coffeeStockService& CoffeeStockService){
    CoffeeStockService.restockBeans(CoffeeStorage);
}

void coffeeMachine::emptyGrounds(coffeeStorage& CoffeeStorage, coffeeStockService& CoffeeStockService){
    CoffeeStockService.emptyTrash(CoffeeStorage);
}

TEST(MockObjTest, TestObjectCallsWithMock) {

    mockCoffeeStorage mockedCoffeeStorage;
    mockCoffeeStockService mockedCoffeeStockService;

    EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStorage, checkWater())
        .Times(AtLeast(1));

    EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStorage, checkBeans())
        .Times(AtLeast(1));

    EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStorage, takeCoffeeStorage())
        .Times(AtLeast(1));

    coffeeMachine coffeeTest = coffeeMachine(&mockedCoffeeStorage, &mockedCoffeeStockService);

    std::cout<< "Address of mockedCoffeeStorage: " << &mockedCoffeeStorage << "\n";
    std::cout<< "Address of mockedCoffeeStockService: " << &mockedCoffeeStockService << "\n";

    // EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStockService, restockWater(mockedCoffeeStorage))
    //     .Times(AtLeast(1));
    // EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStockService, restockBeans(mockedCoffeeStorage))
    //     .Times(AtLeast(1));
    // EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStockService, emptyTrash(mockedCoffeeStorage))
    //     .Times(AtLeast(1));

    coffeeTest.start("en");



       for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if(coffeeTest.getBeansContent(mockedCoffeeStorage) < 5)
            coffeeTest.fillBeans(mockedCoffeeStorage, mockedCoffeeStockService);
        if(coffeeTest.getGroundsContent(mockedCoffeeStorage) > 20)
            coffeeTest.emptyGrounds(mockedCoffeeStorage, mockedCoffeeStockService);
        if(coffeeTest.getTankContent(mockedCoffeeStorage) < 15)
            coffeeTest.fillTank(mockedCoffeeStorage, mockedCoffeeStockService);

        coffeeTest.takeCoffee(mockedCoffeeStorage);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: I tried to add more detail but I had to include a lot of code to see how the project is setup. It's very simplistic

Comment: The code here is too complicated IMO, please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's perfectly fine to set expect calls one mock with other mock as a parameter.
2. no need to pass the objects to each method - you can access them inside your functions because they're are members. This technique is called 'dependency injection'.

See this code (using GMock 1.8, so mock definition is slightly different):

```
// pure virt. interface, remember about virtual dtor
class coffeeStorage {
public:
    virtual ~coffeeStorage() = default;
    virtual void takeCoffeeStorage() = 0;
    virtual void setWaterStorage(int amount) = 0;
    virtual void setBeansStorage(int amount) = 0;
    virtual void emptyTrashStorage() = 0;
    virtual int checkWater() = 0;
    virtual int checkBeans() = 0;
    virtual int checkTrashStorage() = 0;
};

class coffeeStockService {
public:
    virtual ~coffeeStockService() = default;
    virtual void restockWater(coffeeStorage& storeage) = 0;
};

class coffeeMachine {
public:
    coffeeMachine(coffeeStorage* CoffeeStorage, coffeeStockService* CoffeeStockService);

    void fillTank() {
        CoffeeStockService->restockWater(*CoffeeStorage);
    }

    void takeCoffee() {
        if (CoffeeStorage->checkWater() == 0 || CoffeeStorage->checkBeans() == 0) {
            coffeeServed = false;
        }
        else {
            coffeeServed = true;
            CoffeeStorage->takeCoffeeStorage();
        }
    }

    bool isCoffeeServed() {
        return coffeeServed;
    }

private:
    coffeeStorage* CoffeeStorage;
    coffeeStockService* CoffeeStockService;
    bool coffeeServed{false};
};

coffeeMachine::coffeeMachine(coffeeStorage* CoffeeStorage_, coffeeStockService* CoffeeStockService_)
        : CoffeeStorage{CoffeeStorage_}
        , CoffeeStockService{CoffeeStockService_} {}

class mockCoffeeStorage : public coffeeStorage {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(takeCoffeeStorage, void());
    MOCK_METHOD1(setWaterStorage, void(int amount));
    MOCK_METHOD1(setBeansStorage, void(int amount));
    MOCK_METHOD0(emptyTrashStorage, void());
    MOCK_METHOD0(checkWater, int());
    MOCK_METHOD0(checkBeans, int());
    MOCK_METHOD0(checkTrashStorage, int());
};

class mockCoffeeStockService : public coffeeStockService {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(restockWater, void(coffeeStorage& storeage));
};

struct MockObjTest : public testing::Test {
    mockCoffeeStorage mockedCoffeeStorage;
    mockCoffeeStockService mockedCoffeeStockService;

    coffeeMachine coffeeTest = coffeeMachine(&mockedCoffeeStorage, &mockedCoffeeStockService);
};

TEST_F(MockObjTest, When_FillingTank_Then_RestocksWater) {
    // assert
    EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStockService, restockWater(testing::Ref(mockedCoffeeStorage)));

    // act
    coffeeTest.fillTank();
}

TEST_F(MockObjTest, Given_NoWater_When_TakingCoffee_Then_CoffeeNotServed) {
    // arrange
    EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStorage, checkWater()).WillOnce(testing::Return(0));

    // act
    coffeeTest.takeCoffee();

    // assert
    ASSERT_FALSE(coffeeTest.isCoffeeServed());
}

TEST_F(MockObjTest, Given_EnoughWaterWaterAndBeans_When_TakingCoffee_Then_takeCoffeeStorageAndCoffeeServed) {
    // arrange
    EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStorage, checkWater()).WillOnce(testing::Return(1));
    EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStorage, checkBeans()).WillOnce(testing::Return(1));
    EXPECT_CALL(mockedCoffeeStorage, takeCoffeeStorage()); // this is more of the 'assert' part, but it cannot be moved to the end of the test

    // act
    coffeeTest.takeCoffee();

    // assert
    ASSERT_TRUE(coffeeTest.isCoffeeServed());
}
```

This is trimmed and simplified version of your code, but this should get you running. Always try to start with some v. easy, minimal test and build from this adding more complexity. If the tests becomes too complex/complicated, it is probably time to separate some parts of your code to the new class and test this class in separation.